# Css linear gradient not working as expected in mozilla firefox

Tags: css, firefox, linear-gradients

I have problem with linear gradient in mozilla firefox. Following css code:

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, black 20%, darkorange);
```

```css
html {
  height:100vh;/* demo purpose*/
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, black 20%, darkorange);
}
```

For all browser produces nice background smoothly transforming from black to orange color. However it doesn't work in Firefox. It produces lot of thin orange and black lines one each after other. However, when I change first parameter to `90deg` (horizontal gradient), it works as it is supposed to. What I'm doing wrong? I've read similiar question from stackoverflow about this problem, but no solution worked for me. And yes, I tried to change to `-moz-linear-gradient` and it isn't working either (I'm using latest version of FF browser, so it shouldn't be a factor anyway.

Thank you for help in advance.

[JS-fiddle link (not much to fiddle there though):](https://jsfiddle.net/c2a8q3pa/)

Hmm I tested here in code snipped added by GCyrillus and it's working correctly. However when I'm testing it in my browser or JS Fiddle it still produces strange result as shown in this image:
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJpx.jpg)

Comment: latest chrome & ff on win7, result are similar, nothing wrong . What OS do you test with ?

Comment: I'm using windows 10.

Comment: What is the height of the container element?

Comment: minimal demo here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRPdyB if you want to play with and check it out. (did you tune hardware setting in FF ?)

Comment: Hmm sorry but I don't understand - how I am supposed to tune my hardware settings in FF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure the element you're setting a background on has a height, either explicitly set or due to content.

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, black 20%, darkorange);
  float: left;
}
#test1 {
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="test1">Test</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
```